# Redirecting to Route results in a blank page

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes

I am trying to redirect to a `controller` via redirection to a `Route` in `Laravel`. What I've defined in `LoginController.php` and `RegisterController.php` are as follows:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/S1CheckUserTables';
```

In the `web.php` I have written the following route:

```
Route::get('/S1CheckUserTables', 'S1CheckUserTablesController@index')->name('S1CheckUserTables');
```

It was working fine previously but after installing `Laravel Version 5.3.30` (the version I was using previously was `5.3.29`) the browser displays a blank page with the following address in the address bar:

```
http://localhost/S1CheckUserTables
```

Would you please tell me what am I doing wrong that the direction in not happening to the assumed controller? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can we please see your S1CheckUserTablesController?

Comment: Have you got an errors in you log?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I've deleted the project and can not say what it was. It was something like: `http://localhost/S1CheckUserTables not found`. Has the error occurred because of wrong routing?